# React setState with callback in functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, use-state

I have a very simple example I wrote in a class component:

```
    setErrorMessage(msg) {
      this.setState({error_message: msg}, () => {
          setTimeout(() => {
              this.setState({error_message: ''})
          }, 5000);
      });
    }
```

So here I call the `setState()` method and give it a callback as a second argument.

I wonder if I can do this inside a functional component with the useState hook.

As I know you can not pass a callback to the setState function of this hook. And when I use the `useEffect` hook - it ends up in an infinite loop:

[image]

So I guess - this functionality is not included into functional components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback functionality isn't available in react-hooks, but you can write a simple get around using `useEffect` and `useRef`.

```
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')
const isChanged = useRef(false);
useEffect(() => {
   if(errorMessage) { // Add an existential condition so that useEffect doesn't run for empty message on first rendering
       setTimeout(() => {
          setErrorMessage('');
       }, 5000);
   }

}, [isChanged.current]); // Now the mutation will not run unless a re-render happens but setErrorMessage does create a re-render

const addErrorMessage = (msg) => {
  setErrorMessage(msg);
  isChanged.current = !isChanged.current; // intentionally trigger a change
}
```

The above example is considering the fact that you might want to set errorMessage from somewhere else too where you wouldn't want to reset it. If however you want to reset the message everytime you setErrorMessage, you can simply write a normal useEffect like

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(errorMessage !== ""){ // This check is very important, without it there will be an infinite loop
        setTimeout(() => {
              setErrorMessage('');
         }, 5000);
    }

}, [errorMessage])
```

Comment: Yes thank u. I found the solution with the if (successfullyCreatedCard !== {}) by myself. But the thing with the useRef sounds interesting. I don't completly undestand it yet but I will learn it. Thank u.

Comment: Your answer works well, but if there are five callbacks, do I need to create five separate refs and `useEffect` hooks? Is there a more efficient way to address this issue?