# How to use cb function in useState hook

Tags: reactjs

I have a class component where after updating state,I am calling a function immediately as a callback func in setState.

Code

```
this.setState(
      {
        selectedOption: resp?.vatTaxName,
        isUpdateVatTax: !!resp?.vatTaxName,
        vatTaxRate: resp?.vatTaxRate,
        vatTaxName: resp?.vatTaxName,
        vatTaxId: resp?.vatTaxId,
      },
      () => this.checkVatEnabled(this.state.selectedOption),
)
```

I want to use the same code in functional component,How I can achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \`setState\` callback on react hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247433/how-to-use-setstate-callback-on-react-hooks)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState with callback in functional components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61840817/react-setstate-with-callback-in-functional-components)

Comment: I checked the example and what would the code look like?
I get that with useEffect ,we can achieve this but I am not sure how to implement this.